# PHP code within IF statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm after a bit of help as I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to put php code in an IF statement:

I have the following code:

```
<aside class="sidebar top">

<?php if(get_field('quote-text')): ?>
<div id="sidebar-testimonials">
<div class="quote-image">
<?php 
$image = get_field('quote_image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?> 
</div>

<div id="quote-text">
"<?php the_field('quote-text'); ?>"
</div>
<span>
<?php the_field('quote-name'); ?>
</span>
</div>          
<?php endif; ?>     

</aside>
```

I'm trying to put the above code in the below code, where it says "Testimonial off" but not in the "Testimonial On" section.

```
<?php 
$values = get_field( "display_testimonial" );
if ( $values ) {
echo "Testimonial Off";
} else {
echo "Testimonial On";
}
?>
```

Every time I try I'm getting PHP errors, can anyone help me out?

I have tried to merge the two codes together but I can get the sidebar to show in the else statement now:

```
<?php 
$values = get_field( "display_testimonial" );
if ( $values ) {
?>
<aside class="sidebar top">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'About-Sidebar' ); ?>

<?php if(get_field('quote-text')): ?>
<div id="sidebar-testimonials">
<div class="quote-image">
<?php 
$image = get_field('quote_image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?> 
</div>

<div id="quote-text">
"<?php the_field('quote-text'); ?>"
</div>
<span>
<?php the_field('quote-name'); ?>
</span>
</div>          
<?php endif; ?>     

</aside>
<?php
} else {
("<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'About-Sidebar' ); ?>");
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry for asking, but does this file has `.php` extension?

Comment: echo the variable $values and check whether there is some value coming from get_field();

Comment: Hi @OgnjenBabic Yes its a PHP file

Comment: "Every time I try I'm getting PHP errors, can anyone help me out?"... what are these errors?

Comment: this will return u TRUE FALSE ???? get_field( "display_testimonial" ) ????

Comment: See my answer for the correct way of merging both snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware of correct opening and closing php tags:

```
<?php 
$values = get_field( "display_testimonial" );
if ( $values ) {
  // ADDED CLOSING PHP TAG
  ?>
<aside class="sidebar top">

<?php if(get_field('quote-text')): ?>
<div id="sidebar-testimonials">
<div class="quote-image">
<?php 
$image = get_field('quote_image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?> 
</div>

<div id="quote-text">
"<?php the_field('quote-text'); ?>"
</div>
<span>
<?php the_field('quote-name'); ?>
</span>
</div>          
<?php endif; ?>     

</aside>
  <?php
  // ADDED OPENING PHP TAG
} else {
echo "Testimonial On";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I add php code to the else{} statement eg how do I call the <?php get_footer(); ?> within the else{}? would it be: else{<?php get_footer();?>

Comment: That would work in principle. But if you mix to manx opening and closing php tags then you'll loose orientation in your code file. Instead of `else{<?php get_footer();?>` you could simply use `else { get_footer();}`. In general it is good practice to separate the logic (controller/model) and the output (view).

Answer (score 0):

You have error in else part. Replace :

```
"Testimonial On"
```

to

```
echo "Testimonial On";
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by doing the below:

```
<?php 
$values = get_field( "display_testimonial" );
if ( $values ) {
 ?>
<aside class="sidebar top">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'About-Sidebar' ); ?>

<?php if(get_field('quote-text')): ?>
 <div id="sidebar-testimonials">
<div class="quote-image">
<?php 
 $image = get_field('quote_image');

 if( !empty($image) ): ?>

 <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?> 
</div>

<div id="quote-text">
"<?php the_field('quote-text'); ?>"
</div>
<span> 
<?php the_field('quote-name'); ?>
</span>
</div>          
<?php endif; ?>     

</aside>
<?php
} else { 
echo "<aside class='sidebar top'>";
dynamic_sidebar( 'About-Sidebar' ); 
echo "</aside>";
}
?>
```